# intercept and ignore a wheel event in a QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, events

I implement a UI with Qt. My UI is a *mainwindow* containing some widgets, and a supervisor to manage my widget behaviors. In one of my widget, *outputDataWidget*, I have a QTabWidget, and some other widgets.

In my tabWidget, I have a dataEditor to show points, and I create a "+" tab, to create a new tab. The tab creation is done by a connect function, which is in the mainwindow:

```
connect(outputWidget.get(), SIGNAL(SIG_createNewOutput(int)), projectSupervisor.get(), SLOT(sCreateNewOutput(int)));
```

My problem is: when we use the wheel mouse button in the tab header to go rigth, some new page are created. I would like intercept the signal and avoid the creation of a new tab.
I try to add a filter event in the mainwindow and in the outputdatawidget to ignore the wheel event. Then I try to reimplemeted *wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* we)* and *event(QEvent *e)* of the QTabWidget. Each time, we enter in thiese modification after call the connect (create the tab). 
Have you an idea how to call the event before the connect, or how I can disable the wheelevent of a QTabWidget? 
Thanks

Comment: Why creating a "+" tab? Having a button to do that may be better, no?

Comment: @Boiethios is right, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127109/6385043 for that (Qt 5 preferred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to subclass `QTabBar` to handle the `QWheelEvent`, then call [`QTabWidget::setTabBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabBar) during initialization.

This is necessary because `QTabWidget` internally uses a `QTabBar` with `Qt::WheelFocus`, so the wheel event never propagates to the tab widget.